# Can I use JQuery for performing operation the html elements made inside an ajax success block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax code it is simply HTML code but there is a need to write this code inside AJAX success block:

```
$('#cmp').append(''+
'<div id="lt">Give Your Priority Here</div>'+
                                '<br/><br/>'+
                                '<div id="drp" class="lt1">'+
                                  '<table>'+
                                    '<tr class="select1" id="drp1">'+
                                      '<td class="select11">'+
                                        '<select id="select1">'+
                                          '<option value="" selected disabled>First priority</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op1" value="Processor">Processor</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op2" value="RAM">RAM</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op3" value="Hard_Disc">Hard Disc</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op4" value="Battary">Battary</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op5" value="Price">Price</option>'+
                                        '</select>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                      '<td class="select12"></td>'+
                                      '<td class="select13">'+
                                        '<button type="button" name="button" class="btnn" id="btnn1">Add</button>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                    '<tr class="select1" id="drp2">'+
                                      '<td class="select11">'+
                                        '<select id="select2">'+
                                          '<option value="" selected disabled>Second priority</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op11" value="Processor">Processor</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op22" value="RAM">RAM</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op33" value="Hard_Disc">Hard Disc</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op44" value="Battary">Battary</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op55" value="Price">Price</option>'+
                                        '</select>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                      '<td class="select12"></td>'+
                                      '<td class="select13">'+
                                        '<button type="button" name="button" class="btnn" id="btnn2">Add</button>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                    '<tr class="select1" id="drp3">'+
                                      '<td class="select11">'+
                                        '<select id="select3">'+
                                          '<option value="" selected disabled>Third priority</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op111" value="Processor">Processor</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op222" value="RAM">RAM</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op333" value="Hard_Disc">Hard Disc</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op444" value="Battary">Battary</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op555" value="Price">Price</option>'+
                                        '</select>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                      '<td class="select12"></td>'+
                                      '<td class="select13">'+
                                        '<button type="button" name="button" class="btnn" id="btnn3">Add</button>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                    '<tr class="select1" id="drp4">'+
                                      '<td class="select11">'+
                                        '<select id="select4">'+
                                          '<option value="" selected disabled>Fourth priority</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op1111" value="Processor">Processor</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op2222" value="RAM">RAM</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op3333" value="Hard_Disc">Hard Disc</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op4444" value="Battary">Battary</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op5555" value="Price">Price</option>'+
                                        '</select>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                      '<td class="select12"></td>'+
                                      '<td class="select13">'+
                                        '<button type="button" name="button" class="btnn" id="btnn4">Add</button>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                    '<tr class="select1" id="drp5">'+
                                      '<td class="select11">'+
                                        '<select id="select5">'+
                                          '<option value="" selected disabled>Fifth priority</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op11111" value="Processor">Processor</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op22222" value="RAM">RAM</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op33333" value="Hard_Disc">Hard Disc</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op44444" value="Battary">Battary</option>'+
                                          '<option id="op55555" value="Price">Price</option>'+
                                        '</select>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                      '<td class="select12"></td>'+
                                      '<td class="select13">'+
                                        '<button type="button" name="button" class="btnn" id="btnn5">Add</button>'+
                                      '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                  '</table>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<br>'+
                                '<button id="nc" type="button" name="button">Now Compare</button>'+
                        '<br/><br/><br/><br/>');
```

It is work perfectly as I want.

Now I am using javascript like:

```
$('#lt').click(function(){
alert("I am here");
$("#lt").off('click');
$('#drp1').show();
});

$('#btnn1').click(function(){
var val1 = $('#select1').val();
if(val1 == null)
{
   alert("Please select your first priority");
   return false;
}
else {
  $('#btnn1').hide();
  $('#select1').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#drp2').show();
  if(val1 == 'Processor')
  {
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op11').hide();
  $('#op111').hide();
  $('#op1111').hide();
  $('#op11111').hide();
  }
  else if(val1 == 'RAM')
  {
    // alert(val1);
    $('#op22').hide();
    $('#op222').hide();
    $('#op2222').hide();
    $('#op22222').hide();
  }
   else if(val1 == 'Hard_Disc')
   {
    // alert(val1);
      $('#op33').hide();
       $('#op333').hide();
      $('#op3333').hide();
      $('#op33333').hide();
    }
    else if(val1 == 'Battary')
    {
      // alert(val1);
      $('#op44').hide();
      $('#op444').hide();
      $('#op4444').hide();
      $('#op44444').hide();
    }
    else
  {
    // alert(val1);
    $('#op55').hide();
    $('#op555').hide();
    $('#op5555').hide();
    $('#op55555').hide();
  }
  $('#nc').show();
  }
 });

$('#btnn2').click(function(){
var val1 = $('#select2').val();
if(val1 == null)
{
  alert("Please select your Second priority");
  return false;
}
else {
  $('#btnn2').hide();
  $('#select2').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#drp3').show();
  if(val1 == 'Processor')
  {
    // alert(val1);
    $('#op111').hide();
    $('#op1111').hide();
    $('#op11111').hide();
  }
  else if(val1 == 'RAM')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op222').hide();
  $('#op2222').hide();
  $('#op22222').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'Hard_Disc')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op333').hide();
  $('#op3333').hide();
  $('#op33333').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'Battary')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op444').hide();
  $('#op4444').hide();
  $('#op44444').hide();
}
else
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op555').hide();
  $('#op5555').hide();
  $('#op55555').hide();
}
 }
 });

 $('#btnn3').click(function(){
var val1 = $('#select3').val();
if(val1 == null)
{
  alert("Please select your Third priority");
  return false;
 }
 else {
  $('#btnn3').hide();
  $('#select3').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#drp4').show();
  if(val1 == 'Processor')
  {
    // alert(val1);
    $('#op1111').hide();
    $('#op11111').hide();
  }
  else if(val1 == 'RAM')
  {
    // alert(val1);
    $('#op2222').hide();
    $('#op22222').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'Hard_Disc')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op3333').hide();
  $('#op33333').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'Battary')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op4444').hide();
  $('#op44444').hide();
}
else
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op5555').hide();
  $('#op55555').hide();
}
}
});

$('#btnn4').click(function(){
var val1 = $('#select4').val();
if(val1 == null)
{
alert("Please select your Fourth priority");
return false;
}
else {
$('#btnn4').hide();
$('#select4').attr('disabled', true);
$('#drp5').show();
if(val1 == 'Processor')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op11111').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'RAM')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op22222').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'Hard_Disc')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op33333').hide();
}
else if(val1 == 'Battary')
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op44444').hide();
}
else
{
  // alert(val1);
  $('#op55555').hide();
}
}
});

$('#btnn5').click(function(){
var val1 = $('#select5').val();
if(val1 == null)
{
 alert("Please select your Fifth priority");
return false;
}
 else {
 $('#btnn5').hide();
$('#select5').attr('disabled', true);
alert("You can select maximum five attributes");
}
  });`
```

It is not working but when I use the above ajax code in HTML file and then call the javascript code it is working perfectly. Why this javascript code is not work and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

However, you have to be a little considerate with how you set up your event listeners. You have two ways to handle this.

The first is to register things like `click()` after the AJAX is already in the page.

```
$('.something').append('<button id="click">Click</button>');
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#click').click(() => {});
}, 1); // have to wait for a moment to make sure it is actually there
```

The other (usually preferable) option is to instead us `on` against `document` with a sub-selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '#click', () => {});
```

With `on()` against `document`, it'll always be listening for the `click` on `document` (which is the top-level), but will only call the function if the element that was clicked matches the selector `#click`.

Comment: I am using now :  `setTimeout(() => {
  $('#lt').click(() => {
    $('#drp1').show();
  });
}, 1);` but it is not work

Comment: I changed my javascript code and write `$(document).on('click', '#lt', () => {
  $('#drp1').show();
});` It is also not work.